# Drupal 6 - Add Javascript to a View

Tags: javascript, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to add a Jquery plugin to a view. However, I don't want to add via the .info file, as I don't want it on every page. I also don't want to add it to the header of the view or create a view.tpl.php file.

This [page](http://thedrupalblog.com/adding-jquery-image-carousel-your-node-view) shows how to add Java Script to a Node via template.php. Is there anyway to do something similar to add Java Script to a View via the template.php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example for Daniel Wehner's answer. It assumes your view is called 'blog', and your display id is 'page_1'. This code goes into template.php. Remember to clear the template cache after adding new functions to template.php.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  // Load the blog.js javascript file when showing the Blog view's page display.
  if ($view->name == 'blog' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    global $theme;
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', $theme) . '/js/blog.js', 'theme', 'footer', FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook hook_preprocess_views_view

Comment: Hi do you have an example of how this would work. (i.e. the code I would put in template.php file for a view called 'example')  Thanks!